# Updating Values on database with mysqlserver and PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I was wondering if someone could point me on the right path here. There's a database with fields: `PersonID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `isActive`.

I collect those values from  a form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm"><input type="hidden" name="hdnId" id="hdnId" value="<?php echo $var_PersonID?>">

First Name<br>
<input type="text" name="txt_first_name" id="txt_first_name" value="<?php echo $var_FirstName;?>">
Last Name<br>
<input type="text" name="txt_last_name" id="txt_last_name" value="<?php echo $var_LastName;?>">
  Status <br>
    <select name="status" id="status">
<option value=""  > </option>
<option value="1" >Active</option>
<option value="2" >Inactive</option>
   </select>
   </form>
```

The PHP code when submit the form looks like this:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['Save']) || isset($_POST['Saveexit']))
        {
            $var_PersonID        = $_POST['hdnId'];
            $var_FirstName       = $_POST['txt_first_name'];
            $var_LastName        = $_POST['txt_last_name'];
            $var_IsActive        = $_POST['status'];
              if($var_PersonID!='')
          {
              $sql = "UPDATE vw_Persons SET FirstName, LastName, isActive = ?  WHERE PersonID  = $var_PersonID ";



              $params = array($var_FirstName, $var_LastName,$var_IsActive);


              $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $gaSql['link'], $sql, $params); 
       }
     }  ?>
```

Once the page is loaded I grab values like this:

```
enter code here
 <?php
         if(isset($_GET['id']))
          {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM vw_Persons WHERE PersonID = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($gaSql['link'], $query) or die("<pre>" . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()) . "<br><br>$query</pre>");
    $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $result );

    $var_PersonID        = $obj->PersonID;
    $var_LastName        = $obj->LastName;
    $var_FirstName       = $obj->FirstName;
    $var_IsActive       = $obj->isActive;

  }  ?>
```

So the query updates the `FirstName` and `Last Name` values but no the `isActive` value, why would this happen?

Comment: This code only has SQL Server calls in it despite your insistence it's MySQL.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `execute`.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: when the form is submitted is there any value selected from the drop down or is it default?

Comment: @Just_Do_It , yes if a select Inactive the value of the select is 2, the var_IsActive has this value

Answer (score 0):

well since the isActive field was a bit type field it only accepts values of 1 and 0 so I changed it to `<option value="0" >Inactive</option>` and it worked